# Order by Year element of DateTime in sqlalchemy query

Tags: sqlalchemy, sap-ase

I have a Sybase table, declaritively mapped using sqlalchemy as follows:

```
from   sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base    
Base = declarative_base()

class Appointment(base):
    __tablename__ = 'APPOINTMENT'
    __table_args__ = {'quote':False}

    dt = Column(Date, name='dt_appointment')
```

How do I query this table, ordering by Year(dt_appointment)? Year() is a valid sybase T-SQL function. I've tried including a calculated column e.g.:

```
dtYear = Column(Integer, name='Year(dt_appointment)', quote=False)
```

This doesn't work with the query:

```
session.Query(Appointment).order_by(Appointment.dtYear)
```

Comment: If you can get part of your date as a year then you can order on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [Function expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/tutorial.html#functions):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
qry = session.query(Appointment).order_by(func.DATE(Appointment.dt))
```

---

Note however, that if you use these types of filters often, it is advisable to create a computed column in your table which will only contain a `year` value of `dt_appointment` and create an `index` on this column. This will improve the speed of your queries/filters substantially. [I have no knowledge of Sybase, so I assume that in Sybase one can create a `computed persistent` column, as one can do in `MSSQL`].